# Dropdown Menu Closes On Hover (Error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

Whhenever I hover over the menu it works fine. But, when I try to get to the submenu links and children, the menu closes

```js
/*----------------------------------------------------
/*  Dropdown menu
/* ------------------------------------------------- */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  function mtsDropdownMenu() {
    var wWidth = $(window).width();
    if (wWidth > 865) {
      $('#navigation ul.sub-menu, #navigation ul.children').hide();
      var timer;
      var delay = 100;
      $('#navigation li').hover(
        function() {
          var $this = $(this);
          timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $this.children('ul.sub-menu, ul.children').slideDown('fast');
          }, delay);

        },
        function() {
          $(this).children('ul.sub-menu, ul.children').hide();
          clearTimeout(timer);
        }
      );
    } else {
      $('#navigation li').unbind('hover');
      $('#navigation li.active > ul.sub-menu, #navigation li.active > ul.children').show();
    }
  }

  mtsDropdownMenu();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    mtsDropdownMenu();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-513" class="menu-item "><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i> OFFERTE AANVRAGEN</a> 
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1146" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Zonnepanelen installatie (België)</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1144" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Zonnepanelen reinigen (België)</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1145" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Zonnepanelen installatie (Nederland)</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Don't bind events inside another event-handler, that can cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: because your hover function is directly on a list element `li` and nothing else. You could do with posting your html too

Comment: I am Dummy to Javascript, can u rewritecode for me ?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works just fine; here's a plnkr to prove it: https://plnkr.co/edit/IFaueUhKE3J1K9vY1NkQ?p=preview
(simply wrapped a `<div id='navigation'><ul>` round the top li).
If you still loose the hover over the child-elements, it's caused by something you're not showing in the original question. E.g. adding this css:

```
li.menu-item {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 300px;
}
```

would make it difficult to reach the child items because you, briefly, lose the parent-hover while  moving to the child.